# Reverse SSH Tunnel - Connections Suddenly Fail

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have a couple of remote machines (a Pi4 and a 2010 MBA) on which I have set up a reverse SSH tunnel to my home iMac. This has been working fine for several years.

I also have a Pi4 on my local network which will soon be deployed to the remote location. It also has a reverse SSH tunnel to the local Mac.

Yesterday, I connected to each of the remote machines multiple times successfully. This morning, I can connect to neither. However, I can connect to the local Pi4's tunnel:

First, the local Pi:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ ssh -p19992 pi@localhost
Linux raspmountain 5.10.17-v7l+ #1403 SMP Mon Feb 22 11:33:35 GMT 2021 armv7l
```

Then, the remote Pi:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ ssh -p19991 pi@localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 19991: Connection refused
```

I know the remote machines are up because they each upload webcam images every four minutes:

[Cha Am Web Cameras](https://www.mgnewman.com/chaam.php)

Apparently, the local machine is not listening on the port set up with the SSH tunnel:

```
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN | grep 19992
sshd      86277        mnewman   14u  IPv6 0xf6e95adeb5846dfd      0t0    TCP [::1]:19992 (LISTEN)
sshd      86277        mnewman   15u  IPv4 0xf6e95adec27fe84d      0t0    TCP 127.0.0.1:19992 (LISTEN)
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$ sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN | grep 19991
MrMuscle:~ mnewman$
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: By "Remote" you mean what? Do your devices connect directly to your Mac or using some public service? Maybe your public ip has changed or the firewall was reconfigured or even your SSH host key changed? Check your open ports https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: By "remote" I mean located at my condo which is about 420 kilometers away. I answered this question myself. The answer is to restart the ssh service on the Mac. Unfortunately, my answer was deleted so no one can see it.